# Can a rotating object accelerate by changing shape?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, conservation-laws, acceleration

Suppose an object is already rotating in a situation of no external forces such as gravity or friction. Is it possible or impossible for it's velocity (linear) to change by the shape of the object changing? For example if a piece of it broke off then collided and stuck back to the object in a different spot. It might be hollow inside and the broken off piece traveled from one wall to the other wall of the hollow.

Comment: Note a duplicate, but there is a related discussion in [Intuition as to why the orientation (of a 3D object) is not a conserved quantity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/166966/intuition-as-to-why-the-orientation-of-a-3d-object-is-not-a-conserved-quantity).

Comment: Hint: Acceleration of the COM is only a result a net external force. The object might change shape, but its COM will remain fixed in space, or moving at a constant velocity (Newton's 1st law).

Comment: You mean you are trying to convert the angular momentum into forward momentum?

Comment: Like a spinning figure skater?

Answer (score 13):

If not affected by an external force, the momentum of the object $\vec{p} = m\vec{v}$ is conserved.  This means that it is not possible to accelerate the object by changing its shape. It does not matter if the object is rotating or not. However, if you permit the object to shed some of its mass the situation is very different; this is the working principle of a rocket, which accelerates by spewing out propellant at a high speed.

Edit: The only thing an object can achieve by changing shape by shifting around some of its parts (without shedding mass) is to increase the speed some of its parts while simultaneously *decreasing* the speed of other parts. This would happen in the situation you are proposing, where a broken piece travels from one wall to another. The speed that appears to be gained (by the walls) will then be lost again as the broken piece hits the opposite wall. Note also that in this case, the center-of-mass velocity of the object (consisting of walls + broken piece) is constant at all times.

Comment: For a rotating object the angular momentum is conserved... but manifestly not the linear momentum.

Comment: @RogerVadim That sounds very strange. How so? Certainly, each part of the object constantly change their linear momenta, but the object as a whole can't change linear momentum, can it?

Comment: @Arthur that's basic mechanics: there are forces holding the object together, which provide the acceleration to its parts. But the first sentences in the answer are rather misleading.

Comment: @RogerVadim So if the answer had said "This means that it is not possible to accelerate the center of mass of the object by changing its shape", would that be better?

Comment: *If not affected by an external force, the momentum of the object $\vec{p} = m\vec{v}$ is conserved.* - this is not true (unless one specifically means a point-like object)

Comment: @RogerVadim Conservation of linear momentum holds for all objects, not only point particles. It holds for rigid objects as well as non-rigid collections of objects. So I don't know what you are trying to say. Rotation doesn't cause linear momentum to not be conserved.

Comment: @WaterMolecule take any point in a rotating object, and you will see that its momentum is not conserved (because there is a force acting on it, but this is not *external* to the object.) The only exception is the center-of-mass.

Comment: @RogerVadim I follow you now. I consider the centripetal force to be external since it's external to the chunk of the object being considered. I guess I view extended objects as collections of point particles held together by spring-like bonds (probably because of my background in molecular dynamics). But I can see that there can be a different way of looking at such objects.

Answer (score 6):

It is kind of weird that you are asking it this way. Typically when people speak of rotating objects accelerating, they mean angular acceleration. The stereotypical example of this happening is the figure ice skater pulling their arms in to rotate faster.

This is possible because in the absence of an external torque, the angular momentum $L$ is conserved. Unlike linear momentum $p = m v$, of which the mass in this expression cannot be meaningfully changed by internal interactions, in the case of angular momentum, $L = I \omega$, and $I$ can be internally altered. Considering RKE $ = \frac12 L I^{-1} L$, this means that if you speed up the angular rotation by reducing $I$, you have to expend energy to do that. i.e. The figure skater would have to use stored food chemical potential energy in arm muscles to pull arms inwards in order to spin faster.

So no, linear acceleration of the centre of mass cannot happen that way.

Comment: In the example of the figure skater extending their arms it is always mentioned that they extend both arms in opposite directions. However wouldn't the COM move when they extend only one arm? And, since they're rotating the extending of that arm would be allowing it to continue moving in a straight line so there would be no equal opposite reaction (until it was fully extended or pulled back in).

Comment: @JohnTrainor How do you think that helps?  The COM can't move as far as that arm does (unless the rest of your body is massless), so the arm is always further out from the COM.  Then angular momentum is conserved.

Comment: @JohnTrainor Find some heavy books, then go to a mirror, so that the mirror is to your side, and stand in a relaxed, balanced position, holding the books close to your chest. In the reflection, find some landmark in the background that aligns with the edge of your face. Now extend your arms forward and bring them back in a couple of times - see what happens.

Comment: @Graham It can help because if the COM moves than that is acceleration (linear) from a change in shape. Angular momentum is also conserved in "cat turning" but there is angular acceleration. Is it also possible for linear acceleration?

Comment: @JohnTrainor the CoM will NOT move. Instead, if the figure skater only pulls in one arm, i.e. does any non-symmetric motion, then the rest of the body moves relative to the CoM. This is equivalent to throwing a ball in a floating spaceship. The ball and the rest of the spaceship will move in opposite directions relative to the CoM of the spaceship + ball. The CoM will just move following N1L or N2L ignoring all these internal shenanigans

Comment: @naturallyinconsistent That is easier to visualize. I understand that and consider my question answered.

Comment: As a note the definition of moving the com can be ambiguous as meaning it's motion in the frame of reference versus it's changing its location on the body due to the change in shape or distribution of mass of the body.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible in ordinary flat space. It might be possible in a curved space.

Consider compact 2D shapes sliding around on the frictionless surface of a large sphere. The possible motions are rotations. We can represent them as rotations about three orthogonal axes, one of them chosen to be through the middle of the object, and the other two far away. If the sphere is big enough, it looks like a flat plane to an observer looking at the local picture, and now rotations about the two distant axes look approximately like 2D translations in a plane, and the third axis looks like rotation in the plane. We can use this to draw an analogy between rotational motion on the sphere, and Euclidean motion (rotation+translation) on the plane. The *angular* momentum about the two distant axes turns into *linear* momentum as the distant axes head off to infinity. The *moment of inertia* about the two distant axes turns into the *mass* of the object.

This connection between angular and linear versions motion/momentum/mass can be made explicit by embedding Newtonian physics into *projective geometry*. For motion in 3D we add another direction (let's call it $w$) so we have a 4D space (and we position our flat 3D universe on the hyperplane with $w=1$). Then rotations have six degrees of freedom (one for every pair of axes: $wx$, $wy$, $wz$, $yz$, $xz$ and $xy$), and three of them head off to infinity and become the mass (the ones with a $w$ in them), and the other three stay behind as the moment of inertia. Linear and angular momentum are likewise just different components of the same six-dimensional quantity, as are forces and torques.

As others have noted, in flat space the mass can not change (the distance to the distant axes of rotation is always the same: infinity), and so the position of the centre of mass is fixed. But space is not necessarily flat. And if it is not, we can change the mass like we can change the moment of inertia - by changing shape.

So imagine we have a stationary blob of matter sat on the equator of our sphere. We split it into two equal sized blobs connected by a thin thread, push the blobs away to the two poles of the sphere, now move the thread around the sphere, which is easy because it is so thin and light, then draw the blobs back together to a new place on the equator. We can move the blob to anywhere, without any net angular momentum. If we repeatedly cycle small moves, we can make the blob appear to 'translate' across the sphere just by changing shape. In general, we don't have to go all the way to the poles - we only have to be able to spread out over an appreciable fraction of the 'radius of curvature' of space in your vicinity in order to change the mass/moment of inertia, which makes reactionless 'linear' motion possible in curved space.

However, since the radius of curvature of the universe has been found to be far larger than the observable part of it (14 billion light years), this isn't really a practical notion for long-range travel!